# Jython embedded in Java -- ImportError: No module named yaml

Tags: python, jython-2.7

I am trying to embed Jython in Java because I need to be able to reuse some python code that is parsing a yaml. When I try to run the code below:

```
interp.exec("import sys");
interp.exec("print sys.version");
interp.exec("sys.path.append(\'C:/MyScripts\')");
interp.exec("import MyYAMLReader");
```

I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named yaml

How can I resolve this? I am currently coding in Eclipse and have the jython2.7 jar. Is there anything else I need to be able to run this?

Comment: This is probably because your jython PATH isn't in sys.path. Try `sys.path.append('C:\\jython2.5.2\\Lib\\')` and `sys.path.append('C:\\jython2.5.2\\Lib\\site-packages')`

Comment: Oh, and edit the path so that it matches your install directory of jython 2.7

Comment: Late reply but thanks this worked.